# How to add parameters for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, query

I need to add a parameter to this custom query below.

```
 post_type=customer-stories&tag=microsoft,google
```

I now need to add a parameter that will allow me to customize how many of each type of customer story I am getting from each category. So now, it just queries and brings me back all the results. I'd like to just bring in for example 4 microsoft stories and 4 google stories.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want posts_per_page but you would have to create 2 queries to pull in 4 of each tag as the default code will pull in posts from either of the tags, not an equal amount between them.

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'customer-stories',
 'tag' => 'microsoft',
 'posts_per_page' = '4'
);
$args2 = array(
 'post_type' => 'customer-stories',
 'tag' => 'microsoft',
 'posts_per_page' = '4'
);
$query1 = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
    $query1->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();

$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
    $query2->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title( $query2->post->ID ) . '</li>';
}
```

That should get you most of the way to a solution

Comment: Hey Gareth, Thanks for the help! I'm using Visual Composer for the query, I don't think it'll allow me to write this in there. Should I then put this in my functions.php ?

Comment: you can put it in the functions.php (put in a function first) or you can create page templates (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)

Comment: so I added it to a template. But it's not loading in the correct place. The stories do populate, but not within the Main Content.